# Tracking hits to my website with millisecond accuracy

Tags: javascript, logging, web, google-analytics, web-analytics

I am conducting a user study in which users will be visiting a website that I manage and I need to record exactly when they visited the website. Tools like Google Analytics only give a general picture of traffic, but for this study I need to know exact times for hits.

Ideally the website would be hosted on GitHub pages, but if I need to do something like run a script to watch the site and keep a timestamp log then I could run it on a Linux server as well.

Comment: Exact to the millisecond times for hits are going to be a challenge due to network latency when the browser loads the script, and how long the browser takes to render the page, etc.  If it's exact times between clicks then that's possible a tracking library could implement it using JavaScript.

Comment: You could use the navigation timing API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) - since measurements are done by the browser and only then communicated via a JS API they should be more accurate than "pure" JS time calculations.